# PostgreSQL update referencing row in Table B on Update of the concerning row in Table A

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a small problem and don't find a solution searching this forum. It is probably a small problem, but I guess I'm thinking to complicated today.

I have two tables A & B.

```
Table A
a_id
a_name
a_costs
...

Table B
b_id
a_id (FK)
last_update(timestamp)
...
```

Only some datasets of A are referenced in B. Now i want to set a Timestamp for the referencing row in B, when a specific row in A is updated. My idea is to use a trigger. Can anybody help me?

Best regards 
Christian

PS: I've reduced the problem to the minimal necessary information. The DB System is much more complex and following the 3rd normal form. Due to functionality i have to use this structure and it is not possible to simply add the timestamp attribute in Table A.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ts()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$update_b$

BEGIN
update "B" set import_ts=now() where a_id=NEW.id;
RETURN NULL;
END; 
$update_b$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_b
  AFTER UPDATE ON "A"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_ts();
```